# Google Analytics tracking article based on post date

Tags: google-analytics, bug-tracking

Is there any possibility tracking what article we post in certain date using google analytics?? 
If there's any way possible, please let me know. thankyou

Answer (score 1):

First, your question will likely be closed soon because it has nothing to do with the focus of this group.

Second, Google Analytics reports on visitors and what they do on your site. It will track visits to the site, what pages they visit, and more. And you can narrow down those stats to specific date(s).

But there is nothing that GA does that will report on when you post something. For example, if you publish a post, and nobody visits that page, there will be no GA data.

If you want to track when a post is published, you could write code that does that. But that is not something GA does.